# other webelement is also treated as List<WebElement>

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

After accessing the webelements of List. Other webelement is also treated as List  webelement.

```
List<WebElement> BrandTerms =driver.findElements(BrandTerm); 
js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
{
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+Bandtermsvalue+i + "'", BrandTerms.get(i));
}
js=null;
driver.findElements(By.id("btnAddBrandedTerms")).click();
```

Why is this webelement is treated as list element with message "click() is undefined for the type List"

[image]

Comment: you have to use driver.findElement ( not driver.findElements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively You may extract and click on the first  found

```
List<WebElement> BrandTerms =driver.findElements(BrandTerm); 
js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
{
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='"+Bandtermsvalue+i + "'", BrandTerms.get(i));
}
js=null;
driver.findElements(By.id("btnAddBrandedTerms")).get(0).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnAddBrandedTerms")).click();
```

Please see webdriver API specs
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/handler/FindElement.html

and
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server/handler/FindElements.html

Also highly recommending to double check [selenium top tips and tricks](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/selenium_webdriver_tips_tricks/) and try that out in your project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

findElements returns a list of all the elements which match given xpath. Whereas, findElement returns first matching element using the xpath. But, be careful as if there is no element matching the given xpath, you may face exception.

To solve the issue you are facing, instead of below line:

```
driver.findElements(By.id("btnAddBrandedTerms")).click();
```

Please use this line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("btnAddBrandedTerms")).click();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its result of code copy and paste. Thanks for point out.